# If $l=lcm(n,m)$ and $x$ is a common multiple of $n$ and $m$, prove $l|x$ using quotient remainder thm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

lcm is the least common multiple and n,m are positive integers.
Do I somehow incorporate the fact that $n|x$ and $m|x$?

Comment: If $x$ is a common multiple of $n$ and $m$, then it can be rewritten as $$x=\text{lcm}(n,m)\times a$$ for some $a\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: It follows that $$x=l\times a \Rightarrow l \mid x $$

Comment: The question depends on exactly what properties of lcm(,) are you allowed to use. In other words, what context does this question belong to?

Comment: it is simply a proof to show that $l$ divides $x$

Comment: It's easier to prove that $\frac {m}{\gcd(m,n)}\frac {n}{\gcd{m,n})\gcd(m,n)$ divides all common multiples, and therefore *is* divides the least common mulitple.  Then because it *is* a common multiple it *is* the lcm.

Comment: Why are you editing this question until it is incomprehensible and meaningless?  As it stands the body and the question are completely unclear and not at all in agreement with each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By remainder theorem.

For any $n,q$ there are integers $a, r$ with $0 \le r < q$ so that $n = aq + r$.

So if $k$ is a common multiple of $n,m$ then $k \ge lcm(n,m)$ because $lcm(n,m)$ is the *least* (non-zero) common multiple.

So there is an $a$ and $r; 0 \le r < lcm(m,n)$ so that $k = a*lcm(m,n) + r$.  As $n|k$ and $n|lcm(m,n)$ then $n|r$.  And as $m|k$ and $m|lcm(m,n)$ then $m|r$.  So $r$ is a common multiple of $n$ and $m$.

But $r < lcm(m,n)$ which is the *least* common multiple of $m,n$.  The only common multiples that can be less then than the least are the "trick" ones $r=0$ (or $r < 0$).  So $r = 0$ and $k = a*lcm(m,n)$ and $lcm(m,n)$ divides all other common multiples.

=== old answer below ====

Let $\gcd(n,m) = d$.  Let $n' = \frac nd; m'=\frac md$.  Note: $\gcd(n',m') = 1$.

Proof?  That's standard exercise.  If $\gcd(n',m')= g\ge 1$ then $dg\ge d$ is a common divisor.  But $d$ is *greatest* common divisor so $g = 1$.

Now if $k$ is a common multiple of $n$ and $m$ there are integers $a,b$ so that $k = an = bm$ so $k = an'd=bm'd$ so $\frac kd = an' = bm'$ is an integer.  And $\frac k{dm'} = \frac {an'}{m'} = b$ is an inteer.  So $m'|an'$ but $n'$ and $m'$ are relatively prime so $m'|a$ and if we let $a' = \frac a{m'}$ we have $\frac {k}{dm'} = \frac {a'm'n'}{m'}= a'n' = b$.  So $n'| b$ and if $b' = \frac b{n'}$ we have $\frac {k}{dm'n'} = a' = b'$.

So $m'n'd$ divides all common multiples of $m,n$.

And $m'n'd = nm' = m'n$ is also a common multiple of $m,n$.  And there can't be any *smaller* multiple as that would have to be divisible by $m'n'd$ and we can't have a smaller positive number divisible by a larger one.

So $m'n'd$ is the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$ and it divides all other multiples.

Comment: could you show this using the quotient remainder theorem?

Comment: Probably.  Not sure I want to though....

Comment: i was told it's a fairly short proof that way

Comment: Okay, sure.  Let $k= a*lcm(n,m) + r$ is a multiple of $n,m$ so $n,m$ divide $r$. But $r <$ the *least* common multiple.  That's impossible unless $r = 0$.  .... say that's pretty slick!

Comment: ty for assistance.